# Google OAuth external application in production needs verification, but login still works

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-signin

We configured an OAuth consent screen in Google Cloud Console. Our application is configured like this:

[image]

We only request non-sensitive scopes:

[image]

As you can see, our application needs verification because we added application logo (it is not possible to remove it, arghhhh Google). However, users can still log in without any warning. Is this expected? Will it continue to work forever, even if verification status is "needs verification".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok im going to assume that your application was previously verified and all you did was change the logon.

In this instance what happens is that your app gets unverified by you can apply for verification again.

Due to the fact that its just a cosmetic change ie the logo. It shouldn't take long its just a formality really.

If you check the [needs-verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615#verification-status&zippy=%2Cneeds-verification) link you will find that it states. that if you make changes to your projects consent screen, for example by changing the logo.

> Your projects last verified consent screen will be showed to the users until the changes have been verified.

So your users are just seeing the old verified screen, if you want them to see  your new logo then you have to submit it for verification again.  as all you changed was the logo it shouldn't take long.

Note from me:  I think this is an awesome change, last i checked the app would start to though an unverified app error message to the users.   IMO this is a much better option.  Your users can continue to use your app unmolested while google takes there time verifying the app again.

Comment: Why can users still login even if verification status is set to "needs verification"? Moreover, no warning is shown when users try to log in with Google.

Comment: If you change the scopes then it probably will.   If you just change the logo, name of the app, url to the homepage, or policy page.  Its not as critical but if you want i can contact the team see if i can get some feed back.

Comment: Yes, it would be great if you could contact the relevant team and post the answer here.

Comment: updated everything from the link down is a summation of what I got back from the team.   With the exception of Note from me 

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very informative.